# Verbs that take 'de' or 'à' in moods that are not the indicative

Tags: mode-grammatical

Originally I planned to ask what are the rules involving imperative mood verbs that take "de" or "à".  Then I figured I should include the question in relation to the subjunctive, given that I have only seen the indicative in use.

I am a new French learner, so I am looking for the best answers that will guide us in the right direction.

Some examples:

"Je choisis de prendre cette route." and "Je choisis cette route."
[I have chosen {to} take this route.]   [I have chosen this route.]

The rule is that, when followed by an INFINITIVE VERB, we drop the "de" preposition completely.

One more example.

Je viens de me réveiller.
[I have just {to} woken self up.]

My question is whether you have to drop or to include the prepositions in the other grammatical moods that sufficiently learned French speakers possess, be it imperative, subjunctive, or conditional.

I have seen the sentence:  "Viens [a] vivre avec moi en France."

Is this correct?  I am adding the a in there.  I thought it existed without it.

Comment: Your *viens **À** vivre avec moi* is absolutely correct. At the sole condition of an accent on *A*. Correct. However rare! Pretty rare. I would personally not recommend to start learning french with such constructions. BTW, I would also not start learning french with things involving subjunctive.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be getting ahead of yourself and you are making up all sorts of things that **do not** exist.

1.There is not grammatical relation between mood and preposition: the mood does not point to any particular preposition and vice versa; do not confuse preposition and conjunctive locutions; when it comes to those, yes, there is a dependence of the mood on the locution.

2.You write « [I have chosen {to} take this route.] », as if "to" were optional; it's not, I do not understand what you are driving at.
Anyway the translation of the French is "I choose to take this route" and "I choose this route.". Moreover there is no such "de" dropping rule, let me tell you, that's complete gibberish. If you remove preposition **and** verb you do get a correct sentence that can be taken to mean the same thing, but yet, that is so only sometimes.

3."je viens de me réveiller.", in English is simply "I just woke up."; you write "I have just {to} woken self up." and that's nothing in English; you must also be a student of English, no English speaker would write such things.

4.No, "Viens [a] vivre avec moi en France." is not correct; there is never the item "a" there.

5.CONCLUSION: You'd better tighten up, you've got a lot of studying to do!